# How to write recursive factorial function in haskell without if then else statment

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

```
fac n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)

main = do

   putStrLn "Enter a number: "  
   number <- getLine 
   print $ number >>= fac
```

I do not know how to write a recursive factorial function without if statements. Our professor said somethings about lambda calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching

Comment: [Tongue in cheek answer](https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pattern matching and guards are two particularly straightforward ways. Guards are essentially another syntax for if-then-else; they look like this:

```
fac n | n < 2     = 1
      | otherwise = n * fac (n-1)
```

Unlike if-then-else, they cleanly support multiple conditions; one could also write, for example,

```
fac n | n < 0 = error "nah"
      | n == 0 = 1
      | n == 1 = 1
      | n > 1 = n * fac (n-1)
```

which would look much less pretty in if-then-else form.

With pattern matching, one would typically write multiple defining equations:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac 1 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)
```

For numbers in particular, this also desugars to essentially an if-then-else; but for data types with less compiler integration often cannot be emulated with if-then-else, and also often leads to very natural-looking code.

Another very nice approach would be to push your recursion into existing Prelude functions; the more you can spot iteration patterns in practice the more bugs you can avoid by not re-implementing the same loops over and over. For this one, you might use `product` and the special enumeration syntax:

```
fac n = product [1..n]
```

A more advanced (and significantly worse) technique would be to define a new kind of number; e.g. Church numerals allow the producer of the number to drive the recursion, and the consumer (here, `fac`) to just supply base cases. In this style, you might see something like this:

```
fac n = fst (n (1,1) (\(prod, sum) -> (prod*sum, sum+1)))
```

(But note well that this requires a very special kind of number -- certainly the type of `fac` is not one of a function that could accept `Int` or `Integer`!) This joke is taken to its logical and horrifying conclusion in [The Evolution of a Haskell Programmer](https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html).

Comment: Don't forget pattern matching on the `Bool` from `(==)`, which is what both guards and if/then/else are sugar for.. (Haskell may have too many special ways to handle Bool)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

---

Using tail recursion:

```
factorial n = f n 1

f 0 acc = acc
f n acc = f (n-1) (acc*n)

main = print $ factorial 5
```

output:

```
120
```

Answer (score 1):

If/then/else and guards are actually just syntactic sugar for pattern matching.

```
if b
  then c
  else d
```

desugars to

```
case b of
  True -> c
  False -> d
```

Similarly,

```
f x
  | b = c
  | d = e
f x = g
```

desugars to

```
f x = case b of
        True -> c
        False -> case d of
          True -> e
          False = g
```

So you can always use `case` directly. However, there's a rather simple optimization you can perform by hand. If you see

```
case x == p of
  True -> a
  False -> b
```

where `p` is made of constructors and literals, you can replace the whole thing with

```
case x of
  p -> a
  _ -> b
```